# How to add all the pages of an api into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I do know that python has the read_json function to effectively get data from an api into a pandas dataframe. But is there any way to actually read through all the pages of the api and input it into the same dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import config

api_key = config.api_key
url = " http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?release_date.gte=2017-12- 
        01&release_date.lte=2017-12-31&api_key=" + api_key
payload = "{}"
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload)
print(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

I tried with the requests method but this only gives me the 1st page of the api. But I wanted to see if there is any way I can do it with the df method as below. I am unable to understand how to write a loop to effectively loop over all the pages and then input it all into 1 dataframe for further analysis.

```
df = pd.read_json('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie? 
     release_date.gte=2017-12-01&release_date.lte=2017-12- 
     31&api_key=''&page=%s' %page)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read each page into a dataframe and concatenate them:

```
page = 0
df = []

while True:
    try:
        next_page = pd.read_json('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie? 
          release_date.gte=2017-12-01&release_date.lte=2017-12- 
          31&api_key=''&page=%s' %page)

        # doesn't get any content, stop
        if len(next_page) == 0:
            break
        else:
            # move on to the next page
            df.append(next_page)
            page += 1
     except:
          # if we got error from the API call, maybe the URL for that page doesn't exist
          # the stop
          break

df = pd.concat(df, axis=0)
```

Documentation for `pd.concat` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.concat.html). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the quick response. I had 1 question on the solution you provided, what if I want the program to identify the total number of pages?

Comment: Then you need to check the result of each `read_json` I'll edit the answer